# Como regresar el valor de una consulta en mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, async-await

Estoy haciendo una consulta a mongodb desde nodejs hasta ahi en la consola si me muestra el valor, pero al querer asignarla a una variable, me la regresa indefinida...

agrege el await pero no la traen

```
async function getLocationLocal(req, res) {

    var _id = await Locales.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind: '$data'
        },
        {
            $match: {
                'data.tractor': req.params.tractor
            }
        },
        {
            $project: { 'data.id': 1, '_id': 0 }
        }
    ]).exec(function (err, idGPS) {
        if (err) throw err;
        //console.log(idGPS[0].data.id)
    }) 

    console.log(_id);
}
```

la consulta se perfectamente, pero el regreso del valor, ya intente con return dentro de la funcion exec...

Comment: Deja el `exec` sin la funcion anonima. Solo `exec()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debe quedar así tu `exec`:

```
var _id = await Locales.aggregate([
        {
            $unwind: '$data'
        },
        {
            $match: {
                'data.tractor': req.params.tractor
            }
        },
        {
            $project: { 'data.id': 1, '_id': 0 }
        }
    ]).exec()
```

#### Explicacion:

Cuando pasas una función anónima a `exec` el resultado se trasnfiere a esta y por ende no lo obtienes en tu variable.

Se necesita que `exec` te devuelva una promesa para que el `await` la resuelva y tome el valor para asignarlo a tu variable.

---

> ## [Promesas integradas](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#built-in-promises)
>
> Las operaciones asíncronas de Mongoose, como `.save()` y las
> consultas, retornan `thenables`. Esto quiere decir que puedes hacer
> cosas como `MyModel.findOne({}).then()` y `await MyModel.findOne({}).exec()` si estas usando `async/await`

Comment: Entiendo entiendo, muchas gracias por la explicacion, ahora lo tendre en los comentarios que estoy tomando como apuntes